# Laravel 4 Routes with Apache

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-4

I just started learning laravel 4 but I am having issues with the routes. When I go to my root url the routes seem to be working fine but when I try accessing my second route I get a 404 error and the server logs show a 'file not found' error.

I set **AllowOverride ALL** and changed the original .htaccess code to the one I posted below.

**Note:** example.com is working and it returns `All cats` as it supposed to.

This is the code:

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return "All cats";
});

Route::get('cats/{id}',function($id){
    return "Cat #$id";
})->where('id','[0-9]+');
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cats/public
        ServerName example.com
        ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
        CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

**HTML error when trying to access example.com/cats/123**

```
The requested URL /cats/123 was not found on this server.
```

**Error log**

```
 File does not exist: /var/www/html/cats/public/cats
```

Comment: Why can't you use the original .htaccess provided by Laravel ?

Comment: I was using it but it was not working and I saw that a lot of people where changing to the one I posted above.

Comment: Change back to the original htaccess and add the AllowOverride All in your virtualhost configuration.

Comment: I tried adding the AllowOverride ALL inside the VH but I was getting an error so I left it where it was.

Comment: What error did you get when adding Allowoverride in the VH config ?

Comment: I got it. Thanks. Post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. I was forgetting to add `<directory "/var/www/html/cats">` around the `AllowOverride ALL` ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive is per-directory, thus putting it randomly in Apache's configuration file won't work.

Create a new [`Directory`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) block for the `public` directory in your Laravel installation, and put the `AllowOverride All` in there, like so :

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/laravel/public">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Also if you're only hosting a single Laravel installation there is no need to use a virtual host like you did, just change the existing [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive and `Directory` block to both point to your Laravel's public directory, and add the `AllowOverride All` in that directory block.